# @Formula - Native Query Syntax Error in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a One-Many Relationship between FullProduct and PartValue (One Full Product has many PartValue)

I am trying to use the below @Formula annotation - the syntax seems to be right, since I ran it in command line and gives me the correct result.

```
@Formula("select sum(pv.total_value) from part_value pv inner join full_product fp on fp.full_product_id=pv.full_product_id")
private Float totalAmount;
```

However, when I run it in Spring JPA/Hibernate, i get the following error

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select sum(pv.total_value) from part_value pv inner join full_product fp on fp.full_product_id=pv.full_product_id' at line 1

There is nothing else in the error log, that seems to point to the right direction.

I am quite confused - If the SQL syntax in command line is running fine, why is Spring/Hibernate throwing up this error. Can someone help ?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to add `(` and `)` for the subquery.

```
@Formula("(select sum(pv.total_value) from part_value pv inner join full_product fp on fp.full_product_id=pv.full_product_id)")
private Float totalAmount;
```

because it's translated into something like

```
select
  entityAlias1.field1,
  entityAlias1.field2,
  ...
  (select sum(pv.total_value) from part_value pv inner join full_product fp on fp.full_product_id=pv.full_product_id),
  ...
from the_entity_table entityAlias1
...
```

without the () the syntax is wrong.

Comment: That was perfect and fast ! Just for my understanding, did you manually type out the translation or was it generated using some tool?

Comment: It's manually typed. But you can switch `show_sql` to true and see real SQL query fired.

Comment: Yes, am aware of that.  Curious because that your translation was perfectly formed :). Thanks again.